# Changes to h1 heading are affecting entire page but changing the targeted element

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to left-align the H1 with the div below it. My method of doing this is adding margin-left (if there are better ways to accomplish this goal, please suggest). When I add margin to the left side of the h1 element, my entire page shifts right.

I'm not sure why the changes that I'm making to the h1 element are affecting my entire page.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website design system</title>
    <link href='styles.css' rel='stylesheet' >
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Webste Design System<h1>
      <!--begining of colors section-->
    <div class='colors'>
      <h2>Colors</h2>
      <div id='orange'>
         <p>Dark Orange</p>
         <p>#ff8c00</p>
      </div>
      <div id='grey'>
        <p>dimgrey</p>
        <p>#696969</p>
      </div>
      <div id='mint'>
        <p>Mint Green</p>
        <p>#4fe0b0</p>
      </div>
      <div id='red'>
        <p>Red</p>
        <p>#FF0000</p>
      </div>
      </div>
  <!-- end of colors section-->
  <!-- start of fonts section -->
    <div class='fonts'>
      <h2>Fonts</h2>
      <div class='oswald'>
        <h3>Oswald</h3>
        <p id='os-thin'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
        <p id='os-normal'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
        <p id='os-bold'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
      </div>
      <div class='poppins'>
        <h3>Poppins</h3>
        <p id='poppins-normal'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
        <p id='poppins-italic'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
        <p id='poppins-bold'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
      </div>  
      <div class='lato'>
        <h3>Lato</h3>
        <p id='lato-italic'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
        <p id="lato-normal">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
        <p id='lato-bold'>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   <!-- end of fonts section--> 


  </body>

</html>
```

CSS file

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: 20px
}

.colors {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0px 50px;
}
.fonts {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
}
#orange {
  background-color: darkorange;
}

#grey {
  background-color: dimgrey;
}

#mint {
  background-color: #4fe0b0;
}

#red {
 background-color: #f00;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
}
#lato-italic {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#lato-bold {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#lato-normal {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#poppins-normal {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#poppins-italic {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
#poppins-bold {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#os-thin {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
#os-normal {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#os-bold {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.colors div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.fonts div {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 385px
}

.fonts p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you exactly mean by left align ?

Comment: Dude you're not closing the h1 tag, it's open, so everything in the page is H1

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Webste Design System<h1>
```

The second tag on this element is missing the backslash in its intended closing tag. That instead opens a new h1 as a sub-element of the first, and because neither tag is closed, the entire rest of the file are considered sub-elements of both h1 tags and receive h1's css styling.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed a / in the closing h1 tag.

```
<h1>Website Design System</h1>
```